# How to save parent entity without inserting child in one to one relationship by shared primary key in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

> I am using one to one relation by shared primary key in hibernate,
>   whenever I call the save method to insert parent entity without inserying child entity I get below
>   exception

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.sms.domain.Child.parent]
```

[image: Schema of parent and child table]

> Code of child class entity with mapping of parent class entity is
>   given below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_child")
public class Child {

@Id
    @Column(name="user_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
    private Long id;

@OneToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Parent parent;
```

> And in parent class entity i have mapped child class entity like below

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child child;
```

Is there any way to save only parent entity without inserting child entity?

Comment: in parent: `@OneToOne(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, nullable=true)`

Comment: Remove `cascade=CasecadeType.ALL` and try.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: its showing The attribute nullable is undefined for the annotation type OneToOne

Comment: @ujulu its still giving me an error  object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.example.sms.domain.Parent.child -> com.example.sms.domain.Child

Comment: I don't see what you're doing. Post the `Parent` entity as well as the code saving it.

Answer (score 1):

The entity relationship diagram is not showing us a one-to-one relationship. But let us assume it is.

If I understood you well the child entity is dependent on the parent entity and it does not have its own identity. So you don't need to define an ID attribute for it; so the mapping for the `Child` entity should look like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
    // ...

}
```

and the `Parent`entity should look like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="parent")
    private Child child;

    // ...
}
```

That should be the mapping. Now, if you want to save parent without child do as follows:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
// set attribute values
entityManager.persist(parent);
```

But if you want to save child, you should know that you first must have to save parent because the child is dependent on the parent, which means the parent must exist.

Comment: Tried  your code but  its still showing exception "Could not insert  name of all child attribute name like fisrt_name, last_name etc" while saving Parent Entity

Comment: I am at work right now. If you post your code, I'll try it out in the evening unless someone do not answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Finally after 1 day I have found the solution myself
>
> This code Was correct. Mapstruct was creating a problem while
>   converting Dto to domain object

```
@Mappings({

            @Mapping(source = "fatherName", target = "child.childDetail.fatherName"),
            @Mapping(source = "motherName", target = "child.childDetail.motherName"),
            @Mapping(source = "firstName", target = "child.childDetail.firstName"),
            @Mapping(source = "lastName", target = "child.childDetail.lastName"),
            @Mapping(source = "dateOfBirth", target = "child.childDetail.dateOfBirth"),
        })
    public User ParentDtoToParent(ParentDto parentDto);
```

> I was using the Same DTO object that I was using while storing every
>   child detail But to store only parent entity I was not sending any
>   child details value in the Json Format. So mapstruct Automatically
>   assigned NULL value to the Child attribute(firstname,lastname etc)
>   When Hibernate Was saving the object it got object With the Null value
>   of Attributes instead of NULL Object